# Windows7: cmd/ps command to detect file/folder locks

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell

Is there a command for cmd or powershell i can detect (and possibly delete) file/folder-locks.

Something like `net file`?

Edit:

the Answer "no there is no such command" is eligible too.

Comment: Is a third party executable acceptable?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

Comment: @Bob I know there are several tools out there for this purpose, but i would like the to keep it "simple" with a/some cmd commands.